# Are pedal overlap bikes normal?

Tags: road-bike, safety

I received a GMC Denali road bike today, and it doesn't look like the pictures displayed online.

The problem is that the front tire overlaps pedal, and I found it very dangerous.

[image]

So my question is, is this normal? Or should I get a refund?

Comment: While the cause in this case appears to be be reversed fork, there are indeed racing bikes made with about that much overlap.  And, as you have found, they are very tricky to ride, and not for the faint of heart.  (I don't recall the arguments for having such overlap, but it seems there's always a "market" for any conceivable bike variation.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks some track bikes used to be made this way, but I don't know if that's still the case.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**The fork is fitted the wrong way around.** The brake caliper should be in front of the fork, not behind it. The way it is, the bike will be very, very hard to ride because of the negative rake, making it very nervous. The negative rake is also the reason for the pedal overlap. Normally, you should **at most** get some toe overlap.

Loosen the bolt in the top of the stem, turn the fork around 180 degrees (it will only go clockwise because of the brake cable to the front brake) and tighten the bolt when the stem and wheel are aligned.

---

Thanks to @MichaelT, here's a picture of how the fork is supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: Beware to not get the bolt outside. Loosen it for ~1cm, then, if the stem do not turning yet, hit the bolt with a hammer.

Comment: There would appear to be just enough slack in the front brake cable that a determined person probably *could* rotate the fork the wrong way around. Obviously, nobody sane would do that, but still...

Comment: If you do not trust your mechanical skills, it might be a better idea to give the bike back and get a refund instead immediately. If you damage something during your repair, and then ask the seller for a refund (for what reason ever), he could refuse it.

Comment: Or take it to your friendly neighborhood bike shop; they should be able to fix it correctly.

Comment: If it would help the answer: [an image](http://static.bootic.com/_pictures/886699/gmc-denali-road-bike_1.jpg) of the fork of the bike properly fitted with the resolution to see the way the bolt and associated parts fit together.

Comment: Could it be that the fork was attached this way to make the bike smaller for transportation/delivery?

Comment: @Raidri I doubt it. Turning the fork around would give you maybe 10cm in a road bike. Given the size of a bike, that doesn't really make the box much smaller.